# Differential emission of LED die under changing current?

Tags: led, semiconductors, emissions

This is going to be a bit too specialist for most people, but here goes...

Normally we treat LEDs as point sources. However, they are actually flat chips that emit light from the surface. I am *assuming* that the emission is not uniform across the chip. If this is so does the uniformity of the relative emission across the chip remain constant under varying current? Or do changes in current result in different areas of the chip lightening or darkening relative to each other?

Comment: 1) LED chips are quite small so my guess is that even **if** the light emission across the LED chip isn't uniform, you'd have a hard time noticing it, maybe special equipment is needed. 2) in my view the light emission is directly related to the current density, I do not see how the relative current density would change throughout the chip if the whole chip runs at lower or higher current. A temperature difference could cause that though **but** LED chips are quite small so I would not expect significant temperature differences to exist.

Comment: 3) of course you already know that large (> 3 W) LED modules contain many small LED chips which sometimes are't that equal. Run them at a very low current and see how some chips light up more brightly than others. But this is not the effect you're asking about. See this video by BigClive: https://youtu.be/WCNB4lVYZQA?t=107

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie We are using light from a small single chip IR diode to locate a piece of metal for within nanometres using a split beam and then recombining to get a zero. Nothing should change with changing current if the die emits uniformly. Just looking for possible noise sources.

Comment: For what it's worth, LEDs are far from point sources. Even the smallest generate huge numbers of modes, and yes you won't put equal power into each mode or necessarily have a constant ratio between them as you vary current/temperature. Sounds like you want a single mode laser diode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news first: the plastic dome that you typically see on LEDs is a lens / diffusor and probably designed to counter any significant variation.

The amount of photons emitted is proportional to the number of (desired) charge carrier recombinations in the junction.

That boils down to the population of the bands in your semiconductor crystal; you'll need the right states to be available for such a photon-emitting combination to happen.

For that, you'll have to have the necessary electric potential to be present at any place – in other word, for perfectly uniform emission, you'd need a perfectly uniform electric field!

Of course, even assuming your LED's die is infinitely large and perfectly flat, that's impossible if you don't build your electrodes from a perfect conductor; in reality, you'll always observe that there's higher current where there's the "electrically shortest path" between the two electrodes, which implies you'll get less light emission at the edges of your die, far away from the contacting.

And also, the higher the current, the more it will "spread out" across the whole surface.

Now, clever contacting will minimize try to minimize the non-uniformity: in the end, wafer is expensive enough to make manufacturers want to avoid that. And while that will certainly strive to homogenize the current density under maximum I_f, it's unlikely to be wildly suboptimal for lower currents.

Overall:

> Or do changes in current result in different areas of the chip lightening or darkening relative to each other?

Yes!

Also, don't disregard thermal aspects: an LED *is* a semiconductor device, which has higher electron mobility with higher temperature, but also higher number of non-emitting recombinations. But, a well-cooled part of the die might act as a small current "barrier" and distinctively shape how current is distributed in a situation where the temperature delta to the environment becomes large.

this just in:

> We are using light from a small single chip IR diode to locate a piece of metal for within nanometres using a split beam and then recombining to get a zero.

Ah! Yeah, well, aren't you aiming for a laser diode here instead of a plain LED?

Comment: Plain IR LED has worked OK so far and maybe a laser would be better, but we are heavily space constrained. Might be worth a try though.

Comment: Don't worry, maybe I'm just misunderstanding! But this *is* an interferometric approach, right?

Comment: Sort of, but its a lot cruder than you imagine. One emitter, two phototransistors and the metal sitting in the centre of the beam. We use a PID to get a zero when combining the o/p of the phototransistors

Comment: ah! that's clever and elegant :)

Comment: well, even if the light source isn't uniform, shouldn't the per-sensor brightness-vs-particle-position curve always have an extremum when the particle blocks the exact straight path between emitter brightness-weigted center and phototransistor center? If you can fit a parametric curve (e.g.: a quadratic function with parameters brigthness offset, brightness center position of LED, particle position) to that: Maybe with just a couple of measurements you might be able to find the real position of the particle well enough.

Comment: What is the end application of this set up?